# PyMC + Theano on Debian Backports

Tags: python, pymc, theano

I'm attempting to run a model in pymc3 that takes advantage of `theano.dot` when performing the dot product in a multilevel model.  However, when I attempt to import theano I get:

```
python model.py

... // there's a huge output that's looks to be a file

Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
g++ -shared -g -O3 -fno-math-errno -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-write-strings -Wl,-rpath,/home/thauck/miniconda/envs/data/lib -D NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -fPIC -I/home/thauck/miniconda/envs/data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/thauck/miniconda/envs/data/include/python2.7 -o /home/thauck/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.14-0.bpo.2-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-7.6--2.7.8-64/tmpkxtykS/b4f7a60b7c9f9a250601326a9fe2016e.so /home/thauck/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.14-0.bpo.2-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-7.6--2.7.8-64/tmpkxtykS/mod.cpp -L/home/thauck/miniconda/envs/data/lib -lpython2.7 -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas
```

I'm running `backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20140904`.

Conda:

Current conda install:

```
             platform : linux-64
        conda version : 3.6.0
  conda-build version : not installed
       python version : 2.7.8.final.0
     requests version : 2.3.0
     root environment : /home/thauck/miniconda  (writable)
  default environment : /home/thauck/miniconda/envs/data
     envs directories : /home/thauck/miniconda/envs
        package cache : /home/thauck/miniconda/pkgs
         channel URLs : http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/
                        http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : False

# conda environments:
#
data                  *  /home/thauck/miniconda/envs/data
root                     /home/thauck/miniconda

sys.version: 2.7.8 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (defau...
sys.prefix: /home/thauck/miniconda
sys.executable: /home/thauck/miniconda/bin/python
conda location: /home/thauck/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda
conda-build: None

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: data
CONDA_ENVS_PATH: <not set>
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: <not set>
PATH: /home/thauck/miniconda/envs/data/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
PYTHONHOME: <not set>
PYTHONPATH: <not set>
```

I have also tried, after looking at various problem:

```
THEANO_FLAGS=blas.ldflags="-L/usr/lib/ -lblas" python model.py
```

This seg faults.

Also, it appears that I have the blas directories in `/usr/lib`.

```
(data)thauck@ds-th:/usr/lib$ ls | grep blas
libblas.a
libblas.so
libblas.so.3
libblas.so.3gf
libopenblas.so.0
openblas-base
```

Edit:

The cause of this also breaks `MvNormal` in pymc3.

Comment: I use `/usr/lib64`, but I'm on a different system... worth a try for you, though: `THEANO_FLAGS=blas.ldflags="-L/usr/lib64/ -lblas"`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an old version of Theano, as now if we we can't find or detect how to link again blas, we have a fallback that do not cause crash, but cause only a warning.

Update Theano to the development version.

If you installed it via conda, remove it first, the update:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git --user
```

More info on how to update to the development version:

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#bleeding-edge-install-instructions